# Access the content of a cell datagridview Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hello so I managed to get the row where my mouse highlighted it. However I don't know how to access its content.

for example: I highlighted row 25 I can get that it highlighted row 25 howver I don't know how to access its content and put it all in a textbox. anyone?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: `theGrid[j,i].Value.ToString()`  might access it too  I think `theGrid[j,i]` is quite compact.

Comment: ```dataGridView1[columnIndex,rowIndex].Value.ToString()``` just to clarify where are the indexes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the value property to access the content of the cell as follows

```
// the content of the cell
var x = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;

// this gets the content of the first selected cell 
dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value;

// you can set the cells the user is able to select using this 
dataGridView1.SelectionMode= SelectionMode. //intellisense gives you some options here
```

To do exactly what you are asking something like this should suffice

```
System.Text.StringBuilder t = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
String delimiter = ",";

foreach(DataGridViewCell c in dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells)
{
    t.Append(c.Value);
    t.Append(delimiter);
}

textBox1.Text = t.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank You very Much Sir! I'll use this and update you if this works. Thanks :))

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir! This really helped me a lot. I admire how you give examples first instead of giving just the answer so that I can easily understand it. THANKS :))

Comment: How to get access to dataGridView1 variable?  Did you declare it somewhere?